# Why server-sent-event does not trigger on front-end when having both event and data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I would like to make a demo of usage of server-sent events with Express.js by creating an app with an HTML file with a post form and a core JS file using built-in events package of node.js and getting basics in the MDN article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events.

The operating system is Win10, a node.js version is 10.15.1, the only direct dependency is express ^4.17.0, the actual version is 4.17.0.

js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/consoleEvent', function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  });
  res.write('');
  myEmitter.on('postConsoleEvent', function(data, event){
    if(data && event) {
      res.write(`event: ${event}${'\n'}data: ${data}${'\n\n'}`);
    } else if(data){
      res.write(`data: ${data}${'\n\n'}`);
    } 
  })
});

app.post('/postConsoleEvent', function(req, res){
  if(!req.body || !req.body.data){
    res.status(204).end(); // on bad request sending 204 to ignore request, 400 will redirect user to error
  } else {
    myEmitter.emit('postConsoleEvent', req.body.data, req.body.event);
    res.status(204).end();
  }
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

index.html

```
    <script>
      // using old syntax for being more sure in browser compatibility
      var consoleEvent = new EventSource('/consoleEvent');
      consoleEvent.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('onmessage triggered'); // does not trigger on both event and data
        if (e.event){
          console.log('Event: "'+e.event+'"; Data: "'+e.data+'"');
        } else {
          console.log('Data: "'+e.data+'"');
        }
      }
    </script>



    <form action="/postConsoleEvent" method="POST">
      <label for="eventField">Event: </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="event" id="eventField" /><br>
      <label for="dataField">Data: (required, if omitted nothing will happen) </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="data" id="dataField" /><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Everything works fine if you input only "data", but if you use both fields, the server writes both "event" and "data" on different lines, but the front-end event does not trigger then.

Comment: As the 1st write, write an empty string. Then write your content. Change: `if(data && event) { res.write(" "); res.write(...)`

Comment: @RandyCasburn why I should write a space? And also - e.event is still considered as undefined, is there a way to get event string in front-end?